# Set DB role in oracle report

Tags: oracle, report

I create a role in oracle database and I am able to set role to user in SQLPLUS as below:

```
SQL> set role all_temper_role;

Role set.
```

But I need to set this role in oracle report and I use:

```
HOLD_CMD := 'ALL_TEMPer_ROLE';
DBMS_SESSION.SET_ROLE(HOLD_CMD);
```

But this is not working. Please advise me how set this role inside of my oracle report program.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make your role name uppercase, unless you know for a fact you created it with lower case characters:

```
HOLD_CMD := 'ALL_TEMPER_ROLE';
DBMS_SESSION.SET_ROLE(HOLD_CMD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle offers a better way to achieve this through its built-in row level security (RLS) mechanism (also known as fine grained access control or FGAC).We have done FGAC for our report.

According to previous documents,

1) added a user parameter P_CONC_REQUEST_ID
2) added "srw.user_exit('FND SRWINIT');" to the BeforeReport trigger 
3) added "srw.user_exit('FND SRWEXIT');" to the AfterReport trigger

We hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

The Property Inspector (at the report level) contains a "Role Name" property.  Experience has taught me that this is the best solution.